What's the Name of this Debating/Rhetorical Strategy?
I've come across what I can only describe as a debating tactic where, when somebody starts to lose ground, they might begin to use what can be described as obfuscated arguments. In this case, they act as if your line of reasoning or the justifications you offer are too difficult to accept because there are now too many factors, or it has become too complex, making that conclusion seem out of reach for us. Is there a name for this? Or is this just one of many unnamed types of fallacies or rhetorical/debating strategies that we see in modern discourse?
CLARIFCATIONS:
My apologies; let me elaborate further. What I mean is that initially, the topic was well understood, and they demanded specific evidence. Then, in light of you providing that specific evidence, they resorted to claiming that it's really impossible for them to know if that evidence is sound because there are just too many factors in life. Life is simply too complex. In a sense, this can be seen as goalpost shifting, as they originally required some form of justification, and when you offered it, they simply shifted the goalposts. However, what differentiates this from typical goalpost shifting is that they are not actually demanding a new justification; they are merely dismissing the justification you provided on the grounds that such a truth cannot be known.

Option C, "What if I'm the one who's full of crap?" is always worth considering.

Could you give an example of "obfuscated argument that there are now too many factors, or it has become too complex"? It is hard to tell what this description actually refers to. Is there some change in argumentation from then to "now" bringing in additional "factors"?

Agreeing with Conifold that we can't give accurate diagnosis without more specifics. However, I endorse JD's answer since I think it's the most applicable. "Overfitting" is a valid concern in many contexts, but usually you'll see this "complexity bad" argument from science deniers and anti-intellectuals. The truth is extremely complicated more often than not. Although falsehoods can be either simple or complicated, the truth is almost never simple.

Given your clarification, I'd suggest argument from ignorance. "The fallacy is committed when one asserts that a proposition is true because it has not yet been proven false or a proposition is false because it has not yet been proven true." Thus, the argument after justification is presented is false because it's not yet (and never will be) proven true? That sound acceptable to you? I can amend my response.

You ask:

[T]hey act as if your line of reasoning or the justifications you offer are too difficult to accept because there are now too many factors, or it has become too complex, making that conclusion seem out of reach for us. Is there a name for this?

This is the argument from incredulity. Essentially, the thrust of the misleading aspect of the argument is that the incomprehensible or unimaginable (to some specific person) makes something false. From WP:

Argument from incredulity, also known as argument from personal incredulity, appeal to common sense, or the divine fallacy,1 is a fallacy in informal logic. It asserts that a proposition must be false because it contradicts one's personal expectations or beliefs, or is difficult to imagine.

Imagine your math professor presents you with a published paper, and you look to the class and claim, this can't possibly be true! It's impossible for me to read! This is the argument from incredulity. One person's inability to believe is not the basis for concluding that an argument is false. (It's one smart people hear a lot, btw., so if it has been leveled at the tenor of your discourse, you're in good company. ;)

It should be noted that it would be equally faulty to accept a complicated argument just because one cannot follow it. At some point, one has to trust the experts, but a complex argument is inherently less persuasive in reality, regardless of its veracity.

@Chieron "A complex argument is inherently less persuasive". Isn't such a claim undermined by bs artists when they use complexity to pass themselves off as authorities? It would seem to me that complex arguments are inherently more persuasive to people because most people don't have good bs detectors. Just about every sales pitch that dresses someone up in a white lab coat and has them sputter jargon falls under this rhetorical strategy. Milgram demonstrated people defer to authority, and credentials, appearance, and jargon are the three pillars of establishing authority.

indeed, it can have both effects. Though, if the other side actually thinks about it more than a second, this shock-and-awe approach to discussion tends to dissipate. Defering to experts is generally what one would expect in such situations. If the stakes are low, one might leave it at that. But I think that this is only second-hand persuasion, given that you did not get to the conclusion on your own. The students will have to believe the professor (for now), but also leave somewhat unsatisfied.


they act as if your line of reasoning or the justifications you offer are too difficult to accept because there are now too many factors, or it has become too complex

This is an argument that you're over-fitting. It's not necessarily a fallacy. You may actually be over-fitting by using too many factors to explain past events. On the other hand, if your theory explains future events well, it may because there actually are that many factors at play.

Do you have a reference to this rhetorical characterization of "overfitting" or are you just stretching machine learning terminology into the philosophical domain?

+1 Hmmm. Fascinating. 9 instances of the token in the SEP weighted to "Hitchcock, Christopher and Elliott Sober, 2004, “Prediction versus Accommodation and the Risk of Overfitting”, British Journal for the Philosophy of Science, 55(1): 1–34. doi:10.1093/bjps/55.1.1" Looks like the nomenclature has some currency in relationship to considering modeling as an analog of the general nature of representationalism. Thanks! The SEP also has https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/prediction-accommodation/

If some line of reasoning is overly complex, it may be too difficult to fully understand, to evaluate properly, to spot flaws or to be sufficiently convinced that it's flawless.
One might call that an "argument from obfuscation" (which is a name I just made up).
Another related problem is that the complexity may result in reasoning that isn't similar to reasoning we use in any other aspect of life. Thus we may not have good reason to trust that such reasoning is reliable and thus the conclusion cannot be trusted to be true based on said reasoning.
This borders on cherry-picking, apophenia (the tendency to perceive meaningful connections between unrelated things) or motivated reasoning. But what exactly the problem is depends on the specifics.

Like other answers mention, it may also be "overfitting", or their response may be an argument from incredulity.

"the complexity may result in reasoning that isn't similar to reasoning we use in any other aspect of life" - This is a good point.  In my experience, one of the best checks, if not the very best, against faulty reasoning, is to try to apply it in other areas of life to see if it works.  If we can't hold it up to that light, it can leave a sort of darkness in our minds over the validity of the line of thought.


In this case, they act as if your line of reasoning or the justifications you offer are too difficult to accept because there are now too many factors, or it has become too complex, making that conclusion seem out of reach for us. Is there a name for this?

I believe you are being accused of a technique referred to as the Gish gallop strategy:

The Gish gallop is a rhetorical technique in which a person in a debate attempts to overwhelm an opponent by presenting an excessive number of arguments, with no regard for their accuracy or strength, with a rapidity that makes it impossible for the opponent to address them in the time available. Gish galloping prioritizes the quantity of the galloper's arguments at the expense of their quality.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop

My apologies; let me elaborate further. What I mean is that initially, the topic was well understood, and they demanded specific evidence. Then, in light of you providing that specific evidence, they resorted to claiming that it's really impossible for them to know if that evidence is sound because there are just too many factors in life. Life is simply too complex.
In a sense, this can be seen as goalpost shifting, as they originally required some form of justification, and when you offered it, they simply shifted the goalposts. However, what differentiates this from typical goalpost shifting is that they are not actually demanding a new justification; they are merely dismissing the justification you provided on the grounds that such a truth cannot be known.

Clarifications and edits on this site are done within the original question. This will get deleted. I'll migrate the edit.

When you get a chance, just delete your answer. The Q&A format allows for some back and forth in the comments.
